# Chef nodejs depend on ark and windows

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am trying to use the nodejs cookbook and am finding that it has ark as a dependency. Ark has windows and 7-zip as a dependency. I am setting up a Ubuntu box so having to install a windows/zip package seems unnecessary.

Is there a way of not needing the ark dependency? Is this the correct way to use the nodejs cookbook?

Comment: It won't install a windows pakage, the ark cookbook is platform wide and has dependencies, the only thing is that it will download those two cookbooks on your node, not a big deal. If you really wish to don't see them, form the ark cookbook and remove the depends lines (and brace yourself to keep with updates later)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out eventually. So this ensures I have the option of building this type of node on any operating system?

Comment: This ensures the ark cookbook will work as described in the Operating Systems referenced in the `support` line of it's metadata.rb. For nodejs in particular, I don't know which cookbook you're using, so I can't tell exactly, but if this cookbook metadata.rb reference windows, it should.